# How to display specific item from array in Ember.js's template?

Tags: ember.js

Is there any way to do something like that in Ember.js **template**?

```
{{someObject.someArray[0].arrayPropery}}
```

When object structure looks like this:

```
someObject: {
    someArray: [
        {
            arrayProperty: 'Show me in template!'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what's your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You could use: `{{ someObject.someArray.firstObject.property }}` but it's better to provide a computed property in your controller which returns the desired property.

Comment: There is array `someArray` (not and object) and I want to display first item of this array. So I don't know even how your answer is related to the question...

Comment: `firstObject` is a property on `Ember.Enumerable`. It returns the first item of if available. See documentation: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#property_firstObject